# Using the Fibonacci sequence and deduction to prove...

Tags: induction, recreational-mathematics, proof-explanation

Using the Fibonacci sequence and induction prove that

$$F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F_{n}^2 = (-1)^n, \space \space n=1,2,3...$$

My efforts so far:

The basis holds for $n=1$

Induction step: 
$$F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F_{n}^2 + F_{n}F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}^2 = (-1)^{n+1}$$
LHS:
$$(-1)^n + F_{n}F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}^2 = $$
$$(-1)^n + F_n(F_{n+1}+F_{n})- F_{n+1}(F_n+F_{n-1}) = $$
$$(-1)^n+F_n^2 - F_{n+1}F_{n-1} = $$
$$(-1)^n-(-1)^n=0$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you compute $\;\color{red}{F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F_{n}^2} + F_{n}F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}^2$. Computing $\; F_{n}F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}^2$ is all you need, and in this case what you did works fine.

Comment: I thought that is the way induction works. That you have to use the assumption of $n$ to get to $n+1$

Comment: *Using* the inductive hypothesis does not mean *adding* the expression for  case $n$ to the expression for case $n+1$.